# Failure with importing pyscipopt

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to import pyscipopt, but this error is shown. Could be here an error of the path?

**import pyscipopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\amorc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyscipopt_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
os.add_dll_directory(os.path.join(os.getenv('SCIPOPTDIR').strip('"'), 'bin'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'**

Thanks in advance
Amor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pyscipopt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.getenv('SCIPOPTDIR').strip('"')
```

returns the error. That means the `.getenv()` returns `None`. Your environment has not set variable of `SCIPOPTDIR`.

Opening new console or restarting machine might help because on Windows sometimes you need that to use new environment variables. You can also look here [PySCIPOpt install docs](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md). They ask you to set this variable yourself if the module is not installed in the global path.